# Странное поведение кеширования Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, .htaccess, сервер

Здравствуйте!
Опишу симптомы. Есть сайт, на wp, был установлен w3 total cache, но плагин минифицировал js криво (вылезала ошибка `jQuery is not defined`), и потом я его удалил, но как бы я ни старался, в этом же браузере, где и возникала ошибка, сама страница будто сохранилась и не обновляется. К примеру, даже если изменить страницу, удалить всё содержимое, всё равно останется кешированная версия. Я удалял кэш через плагин, удалил все папки связанные с этим плагином. 
Вот .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Add correct content-type for fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

# Compress compressible fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-opentype image/svg+xml

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif                         "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png                         "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg                         "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg                        "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript                   "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css                          "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/plain                        "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject     "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf            "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype       "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff           "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                     "access plus 1 month"

# END WordPress
```

В других браузерах всё работает, и даже в этом же браузере в режиме "инкогнито" всё работает.
Покажу на примере ошибки.

Вот ошибка `jQuery is not defined` в браузере, где не обновляется страница. Этот код был минифицирован плагином.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тот же самый браузер в режиме "инкогнито". Так скажем, "оригинальный" код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? В чём может быть проблема и как её решить? Хотя получается что проблема присутсвует только у меня, но всё равно интересно.
Спасибо!

Comment: В самом браузере, который глючит, кэш удаляли полностью?

Comment: @Visman Полностью. Если открыть DevTools и зажать левую кнопку мыши над кнопкой обновления там можно сделать Empty Cache and Hard Reload, но всё равно ничего не помогает

Comment: @Visman сейчас проверил, кэш сбросился. Интересно почему до этого не сбрасывался.

Comment: Сталкивалась. Вебкитовый браузер вёл себя аналогично вашему на сайте с w3 total cache. Само прошло через некоторое время